# Request with query params fails

Tags: http, go, parameters

I have the following code to make an http request to a third party service:

```
        ... // more code
        payl, err := json.Marshal(payload)
        if err != nil {
            result <- models.HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
            return
        }
        req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(payl))
        q := req.URL.Query()
        for k,v := range params {
            q.Add(k,v)
        }
        req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
        client := http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(timeout),
        }
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            result <- models.HHResult{
                Result:     "",
                StatusCode: 0,
                Error:      err,
            }
            return
        }
        respbytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        result <- models.HHResult{
            Result:     string(respbytes),
            StatusCode: resp.StatusCode,
            Error:      nil,
        }
        ... // more code
```

The same works fine when not using query parameters. But when I do use params as :

```
tokenResponse = <-(apic.httpHelper.RequestWithOptions("GET", url,nil, map[string]string{
            "user" : viper.GetString("userid"),
            "password" : viper.GetString("pwd"),
```

The service is telling me I am missing required parameters.

If I print the request previously to actually doing it using curl/postman then it works fine.

What might I be doing wrong?

Third party service example:

```
https://auth.service.com/v1/oauth/token?user=matias&password=1234
```

Comment: Are you sure the API you're calling expects those as query params? Where does the second code snippet you show put them?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Hi!, yes, it needs them. I added an example in my question .

Comment: You don't need the q.Encode line. Make sure the request has the query params you need. The URL looks like an oauth API, are you sure it expects a GET request, with username and password as query params?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yes, its a GET, with query params. I can test it from postman and works like charm.

Comment: Then log the request, and see if it has everything you need.

Comment: I have logged the request. I am using Goland. I can log the request and even click on it and it will open chrome and execute the GET and I can see the token being replied. Im stun as to why this is not working. :(

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but the 1ms timeout is quite short.

Comment: You mentioned it works with Postman -- if you copy the cURL from Postman, is it just making a GET request or is it including special headers?

Comment: I got it! The issue is because I was marshalling the payload without properly checking if it was null or not, so the word "null" was traveling in my request instead of the proper payload. :( Thanks so much for taking the time to look into this.